# SQL Query - Find out how many times a row changes from 0 to another value

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8 and need to create a stored procedure

I have a single table that has a DATE field and a value field which can be 0 or any other number. This value field represents the daily amount of rain for that day.
The table stores data between today and 10 years.

I need to find out how many periods of rain there will be in the next 10 years.

So, for example, if my table contains the following data:

```
Date          - Value
2018-06-09    -   0
2018-06-10    -  50
2018-06-11    -   0
2018-06-12    -  15
2018-06-13    -  17
2018-06-14    -   0
2018-06-15    -   0
2018-06-16    -  12
2018-06-17    - 123
2018-06-18   -   17
```

Then the SP should return 3, because there were 3 periods of rain.
Any help in getting me closer to the answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have a stored procedure for this. 
A solution with MySQL's 8.0 LEAD function this supports dates with gaps. 
The complete table needs to be scanned but i don't think that a huge problem with ~3560 records.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  SUM(filter_match = 1) AS number
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ((t.value = 0) AND (LEAD(t.value) OVER (ORDER BY t.date ASC) != 0)) AS filter_match
  FROM
   t
) t
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sev4NqgLsFPgtNgwzruwy/2

> By the way, would you mind expanding your answer to understand how
>   LEAD and SUM work together?

`LEAD(t.value) OVER (ORDER BY t.date ASC)` simply means get the next value from the next record ordered by date.

this demo shows it nicely https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sev4NqgLsFPgtNgwzruwy/6

`SUM(filter_match = 1)` is a conditional sum. in this case the alias filter_match needs to be true.

see what filter_match is demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sev4NqgLsFPgtNgwzruwy/8

In MySQL aggregate functions can have a SQL expression something like `1 = 1` (which is always true or 1) or `1 = 0` (which is always false or 0).
The conditional sum only sums up when the condition is true.

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sev4NqgLsFPgtNgwzruwy/7

Comment: By the way, would you mind expanding your answer to understand how LEAD and SUM work together?

Comment: @SantiagoSanMartin i've editted mine answer with some explainment and demos to show.. I hope you can understand now how LEAD and SUM works together

Comment: Wouldn't it be more "expressive" if you write `SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE filter_match = 1`. Why use conditional aggregation when it's not needed?

Answer (score 2):

Use [MySQL join](http://mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Number_of_Periods
FROM yourTable A JOIN yourTable B
ON DATE(A.`DATE`)=DATE(B.`DATE` - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND A.`VALUE`=0 AND B.`VALUE`>0;
```

See [Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t3rvKQpswR8nD6FHPaZWPS/0).

Comment: this method only can work properly when there isn't a gap in the dates.

Comment: It would work. Look at the OP sample data and the result he expects to get.

Comment: Yes your query would work on the current dataset.. But because of `ON DATE(A.`DATE`)=DATE(B.`DATE` - INTERVAL 1 DAY)` the query will miss a count with this dataset https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sev4NqgLsFPgtNgwzruwy/3 because of the gap missing `2018-06-16` that is what i mean.

Comment: I see but that's not the question asked! The data are collected daily.

Comment: true thats why i upvoted.. i also didn't say this method didn't work i only said the method only can work properly when there are no gaps in the date

Comment: Correct, this method also works. I wish I could choose both answers. I have to choose Raymond Nijland answer only because it also works when there are date gaps

Comment: @SantiagoSanMartin it's OK even though you didn't mention that condition in your question.